# Configure GitLab runner to get more CPU with a specific job

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I have a GitLab pipeline with:

- JobA;
- JobB;
- JobC.

JobA and JobB are light and speed, while JobC is huge. Is it possible to assign more compute power only to JobC with the same runner?

Thank you!

Comment: By default, there are no restrictions on how much CPU or memory a job can use. So, unless you are already restricting CPU usage in some way, no, probably not.